# Python csv file creation

Tags: python

> In one battle area, you are provided with a list of monsters to go along with your D&D game. You decide to create a program to read this information and process store additional information about these monsters.
>
> The input Monsters.csv is also attached in this assignment. Write a script that reads this CSV file into Python and, for each monster in the list, adds the following columns for output
>
> - Level
> - Damage
> - Hit points
>
> For Level, the following guidelines apply
>
> - Gnomes are level 1
> - Orcs are level 2
> - Skeletons are level 5
> - Giants are level 8
>
> For Damage, the following apply
>
> - Gnomes can damage 1-3 hit points at random
> - Orcs can damage 2-7 hit points at random
> - Skeletons can damage 3-12 hit points at random
> - Giants can damage 4-24 hit points at random
>
> For Hit points, the following apply
>
> - Gnomes can have 3-6 hit points at random
> - Orcs can have 4-8 hit points at random
> - Skeletons can have 6-12 hit points at random
> - Giants can have 12-20 hit points at random
>
> The code should output to a file called New-Monsters.csv, which follows the guidelines from above, and will provide spreadsheet information (random where appropriate) like the following (attached in New-Monsters-SAMPLE.csv)

This is my assignment. The code that I have so far is...

```
import csv
 with open('Monsters.csv','w',newline='') as fp:
    a= csv.writer(fp,delimeter=',')
    data=[['Monster names','level','damage','hitpoints'],
          ['Gnome','1','3','6'],
          ['Orc','2','7','8'],
          ['Skeletons','5','12','12'],
          ['Giants','8','24','20']]
    a.writerows(data)
```

At this point, I'm getting a permission denied error on the with open monsters file line. How do I fix that and would this code work?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. Was including all the instructions for the assignment really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using `pandas`. You can read in a csv file as a dataframe, and then process and add columns/rows.

```
import pandas as pd

# return level for name of monster
def level_map( name):
    return {
        'Gnome' : 1,
        'Orc' : 2,
        'Skeleton' : 5,
        'Giant' : 8
    }.get(p)

my_data = pd.read_csv("Monsters.csv", sep = ',', header=None)
my_data.columns =['Monster_name']

# process your data
my_data['Level'] = my_data["Monster_name"].apply(level_map)

f = open("output_file.csv", 'w')
f.write(my_data.to_csv(index = False))
f.close()
```

Comment: How would I re-write pandas to show that Gnomes do 1-3 damage while orcs do 2-7 damage?

Comment: I included an example for level assignment could be implemented. The same idea applies for the damage and hit points.

Comment: I re-wrote the code. But now, i'm getting a permission  denied error.

Comment: What is the exact error message, and when does it occur?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    with open('Monsters.csv','w',newline='') as fp:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Monsters.csv'

Comment: It looks like your program doesn't have permission to open the Monsters.csv file. What are the permissions on this file?

Comment: I allowed everyone access to everything

Comment: What directory is your shell in?

Comment: If you're not sure you can import the os module and print( os.getcwd())